# How to read namespaces c# LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How to read namespaces from code? I want to get xmlns:es, xmlns:un, xmlns:xn attribute values, but I get null attributes, How do I read it?

I try like this:

```
XNamespace xmlns = xdoc.Root.Attribute("xmlns").Value;
XNamespace ES = xdoc.Root.Attribute(xmlns + "es").Value;
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlFile xmlns:es="my.xsd"
    xmlns="not_my.xsd">

...

</xmlFile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XNamespace defns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
XNamespace es = xdoc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("es");
```